# if a value is set make a check otherwise ignore

Tags: php, if-statement

I've been scratching my head for a while trying to figure this out.

I have an array which look something like...

```
$param = array(
   "conditionType"  => $_GET['conditionType']   ? strtolower($_GET['conditionType'])        : "all",
   "minPrice"       => $_GET['minPrice']        ? $_GET['minPrice']                         : false,
   "maxPrice"       => $_GET['maxPrice']        ? $_GET['maxPrice']                         : false,
);
```

I need to check to make sure that all books returned are >= the min price and <= the max price, but if these user chooses not to specify a min or max price than the if statement needs to ignore this check.

```
   if(($param['conditionType'] == "all" 
   || ($param['conditionType'] == "new" && strtolower($book['sub_condition']) == "new")
   || ($param['conditionType'] == "used" && strtolower($book['sub_condition']) != "new"))

   && ($param['minPrice'] && $book['price'] >= $param['minPrice']) 
   && ($param['maxPrice'] && $book['price'] <= $param['maxPrice'])
   && $book['price'] != "null"
   ){
      $books[] = array(
        "link"                      => $book['link'],
        "listing_condition"         => $book['sub_condition'],
        "listing_price"             => $book['price']
      );
   }
```

What can I change in the if statement to make sure this happens?

Comment: The relevant part of the condition looks OK. If this is not behaving correctly break it down and debug it.

Comment: @Jon I probably wasn't clear enough, the part where I wrote `$param['minPrice'] && $book['price'] >= $param['minPrice'])` will not always pass because `$param['minPrice']` can be set to false, if it is set to false than it means that the user does not want to restrict the search by price, if that is the case than it needs to be able to pass the if statement

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake. Looking at it again.

Comment: Is this part of a function, or some kind of foreach loop?

Comment: If it takes more than a few seconds to understand, it's overly complicated.  Suggest breaking that nasty if statement into pieces.

Comment: @mk_89 what are you getting for output on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure the parts that read like

```
&& ($param['minPrice'] && $book['price'] >= $param['minPrice'])
```

to instead read like

```
&& (!$param['minPrice'] || $book['price'] >= $param['minPrice'])
```

This follows your stated logic: either a min price should not be set, or it must be less than or equal to the book price.

Comment: As soon as I wrote that reply to you I understood what I needed to do, anyway I still have you to thank for it

Answer (score 0):

you just need to negate this `$param['minPrice']` to `!$param['minPrice']`